# What are the applications of a more general matrix exponential and its derivative?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, operator-theory

The standard, decoupled matrix exponential $\exp(At)$ for a real matrix $A$ and a continuous variable $t$ occurs in the solution to systems of linear ordinary differential equations.

But, this wikipedia article has a slightly more generalized structure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map

Instead of $\exp(At),$ we have $\exp(A(t))$, where $A(t)$ is a general function of the variable $t$ in matrix form.

What are the applications of this slightly more generalized matrix form, and its derivative?